# Error Install Bootstrap-sass (ruby 2.6.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-2.6

I tried to install gem bootstrap-sass, but command show I have problem with ffi. I don't know what my problem? Thank you for your help me.

I received this error message when I tried to run `gem install bootstrap-sass`:

```
$ gem install bootstrap-sass
ERROR:  Error installing bootstrap-sass:
The last version of ffi (~> 1.9.6) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.9.25. Try installing it with `gem install ffi -v 1.9.25` and then running the current command again
ffi requires Ruby version >= 2.0, < 2.6. The current ruby version is 2.6.0.0.
```

Seemingly they were properly installed. `ruby -v` results in:

`ruby 2.6.0p0 (2018-12-25 revision 66547) [x64-mingw32]`

Seemingly they were properly installed. `rails -v` results in:

`Rails 5.2.2`

Comment: from your error message it needs ffi, while ffi only work with ruby below 2.6, my suggestion downgrade your ruby to version 2.5

Comment: Can not fix it? brother

Comment: any fix for this issues, downgrading could not resolve this issue